# Dll errors when trying to run pokerstars through wine

Tags: linux, wine, dll

I use arch linux. I installed wine, downloaded the pokerstars windows installer. It seemed to install fine, but when i try to open it i get the following errors:

```
0108:err:module:load_so_dll failed to load .so lib "/usr/lib32/wine/openal32.dll.so": libopenal.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
0108:err:module:import_dll Loading library OpenAL32.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\PokerStars.NET\\libcocos2d.dll") failed (error c000007a).
0108:err:module:import_dll Library libcocos2d.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\PokerStars.NET\\PokerStarsOpenGl.exe") not found
0108:err:module:LdrInitializeThunk Importing dlls for L"C:\\Program Files\\PokerStars.NET\\PokerStarsOpenGl.exe" failed, status c0000135
0110:err:module:load_so_dll failed to load .so lib "/usr/lib32/wine/openal32.dll.so": libopenal.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
0110:err:module:import_dll Loading library OpenAL32.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\PokerStars.NET\\libcocos2d.dll") failed (error c000007a).
00fc:fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (0031FE94 00000000): stub
0110:err:module:import_dll Library libcocos2d.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\PokerStars.NET\\PokerStars.exe") not found
0110:err:module:LdrInitializeThunk Importing dlls for L"C:\\Program Files\\PokerStars.NET\\PokerStars.exe" failed, status c0000135
```

Comment: Not all programs will run in wine.

Comment: @Moab pokerstars is claimed to run well in wine.

Answer (score 1):

I have just fixed the same error running on Manjaro with I3wm.

To fix the appointed DLL errors, install the following dependencies:

```
 sudo pacman -S lib32-openal openal
```